# NSRegular Expression Groups (matches)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following string:

```
authmod=adobe&user=ibrahimk04&challenge=5Axn6g==&response=3uy8NkHDVLpt0HwT8PraZg==&opaque=KuAj5Q==
```

I am using the below Regex in order to extract ibrahimk04

```
@"(user)=((\\w*)\\&)"
```

but it is returning user=ibrahimk04&. why ? it should return array with 2 ranges. am I wrong ?

Comment: Use @"(user)=(\\w*)(\\&)"

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lookaround assertions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.regular-expressions.info%2Flookaround.html&ei=YSpFVNfdM4uZuQS3uYLADQ&usg=AFQjCNH50o6T1e3LK70EJqezzZTLsRPRhw&sig2=d_A7KtkoZEEDKeHOTR907A&bvm=bv.77880786,d.c2E) to match one or more word characters which are  just after to `user=` and followed by a `&` symbol.

```
(?<=user=)\\w+(?=&)
```

OR

```
(?<=user=)\\w+
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=user=)` Positive look-behind asserts that the  characters which are going to be matched must be preceded by  `user=`
- `\\w+` Matches one or more word characters.
- `(?=&)` Asserts that the matched word characters must be followed by a `&` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
(?<=user=)\w*
```